# We lack a Google + share button

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The Google + button went invisible:

[image]

The HTML is still there and the button functions, but the button isn't visible. This happens for the "share your answer" links too.

Comment: @StrixVaria boo hiss

Comment: Why can't I upvote this?  It keeps staying at 0 score.  I'm filing a bug report.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot Sure you're not clicking the image?

Comment: @GnomeSlice thatsthejoke.jpg

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that the class `.gp-share` does not have a background declared, unlike `.fb-share` and `.twitter-share`.

`.gp-share` just needs to be added to this style:

```
#nav-askquestion, #nav-askquestion:hover, .fb-share, 
.twitter-share, .post-tag, #notify-container span.notify-close, 
.badge, .badge-tag, .moderator-tag, .required-tag 
{
  background-image: url(img/sprites-extra.png?v=4);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: 
  transparent;
}
```

The google+ icon is there on sprite:

[image: sprite here]

Comment: Nice work, I noticed it was still on the sprite